# Avoid duplicate Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, duplicates

I want to ask a question about avoiding String duplicates in Java.

The *context* is: an XML with tags and attributes like this one:

```
<product id="PROD" name="My Product"...></product>
```

With JibX, this XML is marshalled/unmarshalled in a class like this:

```
public class Product{
private String id;
private String name;
// constructor, getters, setters, methods  and so on
}
```

The program is a long-time batch processing, so Product objects are created, used, copied, etc.

Well, the *question* is:
When I analysed the execution with software like *Eclipse memory analyzer (MAT)*, I found several duplicated Strings. For example, in the id attribute, the *PROD* value is duplicated around 2000 instances, etc.

How can I avoid this situation? Other attributes in Product class may change their value along the execution, but attrs like *id*, *name*... don't change so frequently.

I have readed something about *String.intern()* method, but I haven't used yet and I'm not sure it's a solution for this. Could I define the most frequent values in those attributes like *static final* constants in the class?

I hope I'd have expressed my question in a right way.
Any help or advice is very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have duplicate id's, how are you differentiating between two Product objects?

Comment: @Suresh, the product is the same, but it's been instantiated in different moments and/or executions along the process. A request creates the product, another different request creates other instances, etc. So, those instances contain the String _PROD_ duplicated and that memory analyzer detects a memory waste.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*interning* would be the right solution, if you really have a problem. Java stores String literals and a lot of other Strings in an internal pool and whenever a new String is *about to be* created, the JVM first checks, if the String is already in the pool. If yes, it will not create a new instance but pass the reference to the *interned* String object.

There are two ways to control this behaviour:

```
String interned = String.intern(aString); // returns a reference to an interned String
String notInterned = new String(aString); // creates a new String instance (guaranteed)
```

So *maybe*, the libraries really create new instances for all xml attribute values. This is possible and you won't be able to change it.

---

*intern* has a global effect. An interned String is immediatly available "for any object" (this view doesn't really make sense, but it may help to understand it).

So, lets say we have a line in class `Foo`, method `foolish`:

```
String s = "ABCD";
```

String literals are interned immediatly. JVM checks, if "ABCD" is already in the pool, if not, "ABCD" is stored in the pool. The JVM assigns a reference to the interned String to `s`.

Now, maybe in another class `Bar`, in method `barbar`:

```
String t = "AB"+"CD";
```

Then the JVM will intern "AB" and "CD" like above, create the concatenated String, look, if it is intered already, Hey, yes it is, and assign the reference to the interned String "ABCD" to `t`.

---

Calling `"PROD".intern()` may work or fail. Yes, it *will* intern the String `"PROD"`. But there's a chance, that jibx really creates new Strings for attribute values with

```
String value = new String(getAttributeValue(attribute));
```

In that case, *value* will not have a reference to an interned String (even if `"PROD"` is in the pool) but a reference to a new String instance on the heap.

And, to the other question in your command: this happens at runtime only. Compiling simply creates class files, the String pool is a datastructure on the object heap and that is used by the JVM, that executes the application.

Comment: @Andreas, I'd try interning. Thank you too

Comment: @Andreas_D, one question: Does _String.intern()_ intern at a class level or JVM level? Thanks

Comment: @yaki_nuka - the pool is a JVM internal datastructure and we can't access it throgh byte code (iaw - with Java/Scala/... programs). No one can "see", which Strings are actually interned.

Comment: @Andreas_D, Well, I'm reading again, and maybe my question is not well-formed. I'm not trying to access the JVM datastructure. My question is: in Class A I write _"ABCD".intern()_ and in Class B I write _"ABCD".intern()_ again. How many internet Strings are there? Reading JavaDoc (1.4.2 version), I think there is one "ABCD" instance (not one for A and another one for B). Thanks again

Comment: (excuse me, I want to write _interned Strings_, no _internet Strings_)

Comment: @Andreas_D, I understand _interning_ a little more because of your explanations, so thanks. Another question about it: I have "PROD" String in my XML, and JibX wrote that value in _id_ attribute at execution time. Does `id.intern()` work for me? Or only does `"PROD"` or `"PROD".intern()` work? And when does JVM intern the Strings? In compile, in execution time? Thanks again

Answer (score 6):

While [`String.intern()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) could solve that problem by reducing each value to a single unique `String` instance, it would introduce another problem: every `intern()`-ed `String` can survive for a long time in the JVM. If the IDs vary a lot (i.e. they are not part of a limited set, but can be any value), then this can have massive negative effects in the long run.

*Edit*: I used to claim that `intern()`-ed Strings can't ever be GCed, but @nanda proved me wrong with [this JavaWorld article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-12/01-qa-1212-intern.html). While this somewhat reduces the problem introduced by `intern()` it's still not entirely removed: the pool provided by `intern()` can't be controlled and can have unexpected results with regards to garbage-collection).

Luckily [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) provides a solution in the form of the [`Interner`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interner.html) interface and it's helper class [`Interners`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interners.html): Using [`Interners.newStrongInterner()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interners.html#newStrongInterner%28%29) you can create an object that can act as a "pool" of unique `String` objects much in the same way as `String.intern()` does, except that the pool is bound to that instance and if you discard the pool, then the content can become eligible for garbage collection as well.

Comment: Good point. I'm guessing, though, that this is not necessarily a problem for a batch-process...

Comment: intern is garbage collected: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-12/01-qa-1212-intern.html

Comment: @Lukas: If the batch-process starts in its own JVM that's stopped after the batch is done *and* the batch only works on a single unit of work, then yes: that should not be a problem. But I've seen JVMs run some scheduling software to run what are essentially "batch processes" inside a single long-running JVM. In those cases it *would* be a problem.

Comment: @nanda: interesting article. I need to go through it and might adapt my answer. This might reduce the problem, but doesn't entirely remove it.

Comment: @Joachim: Right. That's what *not necessarily* means :-)

Comment: Please also read: http://kohlerm.blogspot.com/2009/01/is-javalangstringintern-really-evil.html

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll try something from your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, interning is the correct solution and you'd done your homework (that is checking with profiler that this is the problem).

Interning can cause problem if you store too much. The permgen memory needs to be increased. Despite what some people said, interned Strings are also garbage collected, so if some strings are not used anymore, it will be object to be garbage collected.

Some supporting articles:

1. My blog: http://blog.firdau.si/2009/01/06/java-tips-memory-optimization-for-string/
2. Does intern garbage collected?: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-12/01-qa-1212-intern.html
3. Busting the 'Busting String.intern() Myths': http://kohlerm.blogspot.com/2009/01/is-javalangstringintern-really-evil.html

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

You could try is to define an `<xs:enumeration/>` restriction on your `@id` attribute (if your domain model would allow such a thing). If JibX is as intelligent as [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) or other XML-Java mapping standards, then this could be mapped as a Java `enum` with constant literals, which can be reused heavily.

I would try that for the `ID` value, since it kinda looks like an enumeration to me...

Comment: it's a good idea, but not for my problem. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

As everyone know, String objects can be created in two ways, by using the literals and through new operator.

If you use a literal like `String test = "Sample";` then this will be cached in String object pool. So interning is not required here as by default the string object will be cached.

But if you create a string object like String test = new String("Sample"); then this string object will not be added to the string pool. So here we need to use `String test = new String("Sample").intern();` to forcefully push the string object to the string cache.

So it is always advisable to use string literals than new operator.

So in your case private static final String id = "PROD"; is the right solution.