# Find how many unique substrings possible with a given string

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to find how many distinct substrings are possible for a given string. I came up with the following code:

```
public static long process(String s) {
    long count = 0;
    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < s.length() - i + 1; j++) {
            String a = s.substring(j, i + j);
            if (!set.contains(a))
                set.add(a);
        }
        count += set.size();
    }
    count++;
    return count;
}
```

I have taken this code using this: [finding all distinct substring of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213783/finding-all-distinct-substring-of-a-string). Now when I used this for large inputs I am getting errors like for some inputs the program is not running within time limits.

How to improve this code further?

Also I even tried the [suffix tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-distinct-substrings-string-using-suffix-trie/) approach but same issue, it fails with timeout errors.

Comment: All you need is the count?  If I'm figuring this right: A given string length *n* contains *n* substrings of length 1, *n-1* substrings of length 2, *n-2* substrings of length 3, ... to 1 substring of length *n*.  Feels like the number of substrings should be (n^2 + n) / 2.

Comment: Just for fun, try running with Java 6.

Comment: @markspace and the current duplicate check?

Comment: OK, "distinct" means "unique" good point.  (I'll leave my wrong answer up anyway.)  Although if the OP is indeed using a set, checking for contains before adding an element is not needed.

Comment: @markspace, I removed the check and tried also

Comment: I _guarantee_ that a _correct_ suffix tree implementation will pass the time constraints. The article you linked uses a suboptimal method of building the suffix tree in O(N^2), when it can be done much faster. You want to construct the suffix tree with ukkonen's: https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-tree-ukkonen.html

Comment: You could also use a ternary search trie to insert the substrings and count distinct inserts i.e. new words that are inserted.

Comment: FWIW - the current version won't even give you the correct answer.  The `set` variable should be outside of the loop (and then the `count += ...` becomes unnecessary).

Comment: And `if (!set.contains(a)) set.add(a);` could be just `set.add(a);`

Comment: How long at most the string? and what's the site ?