# Get all substrings which are unique

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working on a program which calculates all possible distinct continuous substrings of a given input string.

Here is my program:

```
public int getAllUniqueSubset(String str) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < str.length() - i; j++) {
                String elem = str.substring(j, j + (i+1));
                if (!set.contains(elem)) {
                    set.add(elem);
                }
            }
        }
        return set.size();
    }
```

Now when I used this during an online exam few days back, it failed with timeout errors as the input string length can be up to 10 power 5.

Also similar question is asked in this post - [finding all distinct substring of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213783/finding-all-distinct-substring-of-a-string) also, I used same answer.

What is the correct way to solve this program?

Comment: why the downvotes? I could see the benefit of adding 1-2 examples, but the problem is quite clear

Answer (score 1):

String length 10^5 assumes that quadratic solution is too slow. You generate all n^2 substrings and also calculate their hashes, so overall time is cubic and timeout is expectable.

Instead you can build suffix array in O(nlogn) time, then build LCP (longest common prefix) with Kasai method or other algo.

We can see that every suffix `p[i]` has length `n - p[i]` and produces `n - p[i]` prefixes as substrings. But `lcp[i-1]` prefixes coincide with prefixes of the previous suffix! So we have got only `n - p[i] - lcp[i-1]` new inique substrings for every suffix. Go through siffixes and get count of distinct substrings in O(n) time.

Overall time is

```
O(nlogn) (suffix array) + 
O(n) (Kasai LCP) + 
O(n) for counting = 
   O(nlogn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts, which may not be enough to solve your scalability problem though:

1. You don't need the `if (!set.contains(elem))` check, since that's already in the `set.add()` method's logic. It's taking some time to check that (even constant).
2. You might want to change the Set to List (even if that involves larger space consumption), and convert to set at the end, to remove duplicates.
3. It seems that some computations could be done in parallel (e.g., assign to a worker to perform length 1 substrings, to another one length 2, etc). Those will not need to be cross-checked (i.e., the results of each worker do not need to be checked for duplicates). You could try multi-threading or Spark for example (if the parallelization overhead is not greater).

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution from [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-print-substrings-given-string/)

```
public class GFG { 
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    public static void SubString(String str, int n) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
            for (int j = i+1; j <= n; j++) 
                set.add(str.substring(i, j)); 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        String str = "abcd"; 
        SubString(str, str.length()); 
    } 
}
```